# Finding range of interval from inequality

Tags: probability, integration, inequality, definite-integrals

I have a function which is constant:
$$ 
  f_{XY}(x, y) = \left.
  \begin{cases}
    1/2, & \text{if } |x| + |y| \leq 1 \\
    0, & \text{else }
  \end{cases}
  \right\} 
$$ 
I want to find the marginal probability density function for x which is defined as
$$ f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{XY} (x, y) dy $$
I'm having issues finding the right range for the integral. I understand we need to express the range as a function of x b manipulation the inequality 
$$ |x| + |y| \leq 1 $$
$$\implies  |y| \leq 1 - |x|$$
Any suggestions for how to find these? Maybe I could split the integral in two.. Wuuld love your input on this

Comment: Maybe you can sketch the support first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your function is constant the value of your integral is the area of the  region times the  constant value.

The region is the diamond of area $2$ so the integral is

$$ f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{XY} (x, y) dy=2(1/2)=1$$